# Problem with Subdivision Surface after Bevel

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface, geometry, bevel

Creating a very simple figure out of plane with Bevel modifier following by Subdivision Surface resulted in weird geometry.

Steps how to reproduce the problem:

1. I've used a mesh plane,
2. squished z-axis and applied scale,
3. then added 4 loop cuts,
4. then moved middle part with **G** or move tool,
5. afterwards added modifiers
6. and used shade smooth.

Normals weren't changed, all geometry is same as before, no n-gons were created. Why this might happen?

Simple plane with 4 loop cuts
[image: Simple plane with 4 loop cuts]

Bevel settings
[image: Bevel settings]

Subdiv settings
[image: Subdiv settings]

normals
[image: normals]

Comment: @JachymMichal Perfect! That topic was the solution! Could you please post the related link it below so I could accept it?

Comment: Hey :). Glad it helped. I'll mark this thread as a duplicate, so you can just agree with the close vote to link both threads :).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've only applied SubSurf to one set of faces. Try applying the solidify modifier, if you can, then bevel your edges and apply the SubSurf.